# How can you align labels in different table view cells?

Tags: ios, xcode

I've got a static table view like follows:

[image]

How can I align the leading edges of the two grey labels (i.e. Select a category and "These are the comments") **without** using a constraint between them and the view margin?

As these are in different table view cells its not possible to select them both within the storyboard in order to apply a leading edge constraint to them.

(If the start of the labels is dependent upon the trailing edge of the preceding label then a hardcoded value may not scale to different device sized. For example, if the leading edge of "Select a category" should be a fixed size from the trailing edge of "Category", then its absolute position could vary based on the font size etc. of "Category". The leading edge of "These are the comments" should align with the leading edge of "Select a category", therefore  a hardcoded value can't be used.)

Comment: Were you able to solve your issue? Take a look at my answer and let me know if it helps or if it needs clarification. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to give both **Select a category** and **These are the comments** a `leading edge to container margin space` with the same value. In the sample below, I gave both a value of 60.

[image]

[image]

If you would like to change both values at the same time, you could go back into your storyboard and change the value of 60 twice (once for each constraint). However, an easier way would be to connect your constraints to IBOutlets and also store the constant value in a CGFloat like this:

```
@IBOutlet weak var leadingSpaceConstraint1: NSLayoutConstraint!
@IBOutlet weak var leadingSpaceConstraint1: NSLayoutConstraint!
let spaceConstraintConstant: CGFloat = 60
```

Then in your viewDidLoad() you'll have:

```
leadingSpaceConstraint1.constant = spaceConstraintConstant
leadingSpaceConstraint2.constant = spaceConstraintConstant
```

Now you can simply change the value of `spaceConstraintConstant` to change the constraint space for all of your cells.

**Update 2017-05-16**

You edited and specified in your question that you want to accomplish this "without using a constraint between the text fields and the view margins."

Since your content is static, you can follow this approach:

1. Set a distance constraint between "category" and "select a category". Make an IBOutlet for this; call it constraintA.
2. Set a constraint to leading margin for "these are the comments" to any value (set value will be changed in a second). Set an IBOutlet for this constraint; call it constraintB.
3. In viewDidLoad() set constraintB's constant value equal to constraintA plus the length of "category" UILabel.

Comment: Thanks, but your answer is using a hardcoded value between the margin and the leading edge of the labels. If the start of the labels is dependent upon the trailing edge of the preceding label then a hardcoded value may not scale to different device sized. For example, if the leading edge of "Select a category" should be a fixed size from the trailing edge of "Category", then its absolute position could vary based on the font size etc. of "Category". The leading edge of "These are the comments" should align with the leading edge of "Select a category",therefore  a hardcoded value can't be used.

Comment: Oh ok. I don't think that was specified in your original question, but I see you edited the question. Since your content is static, what about this approach: 1) set a distance constraint between "category" and "select a category". Make an IBOutlet for this; call it constraintA. 2) set a constraint to leading margin for "these are the comments" to any value (set value will be changed in a second).  Set an IBOutlet for this constraint; call it constraintB. 3) In viewDidLoad() set constraintB's constant value equal to constraintA plus the length of "category" uilabel.